# MySQL denying access to user with necessary privileges

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a MySQL server and a user with access to all databases.  When this user attempts to connect to the database and execute a query, access is denied.

I have ran the following statement (specifics replaced with dummy data):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@Macinstosh-2.local IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have also verified that all privileges have been granted:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user@Macinstosh-2.local';
```

with results:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user@Macinstosh-2.local' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'a-very-long-string'
```

Using this user account with **MySQL Workbench** I try to execute a simple query against a database with the following results:

```
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'user@Macinstosh-2.local' to database 'dbname' 0.003 sec
```

Furthermore, I can only see 1 (one) database on the server in Workbench!

What am I not understanding?

MySQL output:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'macintosh-2.local';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@macintosh-2.local                                                                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'macintosh-2.local' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*AEA56C875A1D92BB258B4E27CA869B3CCBA49271' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

**Note that `user` in the listings is the altered username for security reasons.**

Even with this, Workbench does not display any database but one.  I think all databases should be visible.

**Possible answer:
I think this was a bug or caching issue with Workbench.  I was just poking around in Workbench and selected:**

```
Server>Users and Privileges menu
```

**A tab opened in Workbench that displayed all the users with the same information that I obtained in BASH MySQL.  It also refreshed the schema listings on the left with ALL databases displayed.  Whatever was going on, it is now working as expected.  I would appreciate if anyone could elaborate on this or point me to where I might do forensics to determine the actual causality.**

Comment: you added user with 'user'@'ip' and seeing permissions of 'user' rather use following show grants for 'user'@'ip'. In Mysql permissions are bind to ip and if you want to access from all ip's use grant all on *.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'pass' and then connect using this user

Comment: @NawazSohail As stated, I simply replaced the real info with dummy info.  I have updated my post to reflect that I am being consistent.

Comment: could you please specify domain part?..in mysql if you want to allow from specific range use %. for example grant all on *.* to 'user'@'192.168.%.%' identified by 'pass';

Comment: try the following command `flush privileges;` this should help you

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna  Tried it, said `Query OK, 0 rows affected`.  Still cannot see the database in question from Workbench.

Comment: Please connect and run the following: `SELECT USER() TryingToConnectAsUser,CURRENT_USER() ConnectedAsUser;`. What is the output ???

Comment: It returned `user@Macintosh-2.local` for both `TryingToConnectAsUser` and `ConnectedAsUser` ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA  `TryingToConnectAsUser = user@Macintosh-2.local`  and  `ConnectedAsUser = user@macintosh-2.local`  So, I don't know where the lowercase `m` is getting introduced, but that might be the problem.

Comment: Is Workbench running on the same machine as MySQL ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No, it's on my Mac.  MySQL is running on an Ubuntu server.  This login used to work, but just started acting this way as of yesterday.  Perhaps an update on the server changed something?

Comment: what if you use IP instead of hostname while granting the rights and then connect

Comment: @NawazSohail  Because that is not how Workbench is identifying itself to the server.  If you could tell me how to change that, I would be happy to try it.  :^)